# Can a plumbed function be defined in another file (or package?)

Tags: r, plumber

I'm having some trouble getting the syntax on getting a plumbed function when that function is defined in another file.

I want to put a standard plumb function in a package.  My first try was something like this:

```
# in the package

#' Get results for plumber
#' 
#' @param client the clientname
#' @param date The date of data to fetch
#' @param config a config file
#' 
#' @export
plumber_ga <- function(client = "none", date = Sys.Date(), config = NULL){

  message("Calling API for client:", client, " for date:", date)

  ...

}
```

and then trying to call that function in an API file:

```
# api.R

#* Get data
#* @param client the clientname
#* @param date One day of data to fetch
#* @param config A config file TBD
#* @post /datalake/<client>/foo
plumber_ga(client = "none", date = Sys.Date(), config = NULL){
  ...
}
```

...but when I try that, I get an `client is not defined` error.  Is there a way to do this?  I guess the annotations clash or something - or do I need to define the function only once in the api.R file?

The same function works if called directly:

```
# api.R

#* Get data
#* @param client the clientname
#* @param date One day of data to fetch
#* @param config A config file TBD
#* @post /datalake/<client>/foo
function(client = "none", date = Sys.Date(), config = NULL){
  ...
}
```

(also asked on the package [GitHub](https://github.com/trestletech/plumber/issues/272))

Comment: You have to set a defatul `client` API Key in order to get this running.

Comment: No you don't, client is an argument I put in, I can change it to `foo` for the same effect.

Comment: You're right. I can see that you're trying to compile your package, right?!

Comment: There is no problem building the package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
#* Get data
#* @param client the clientname
#* @param date One day of data to fetch
#* @param config A config file TBD
#* @post /datalake/<client>/google_analytics
function(client = "none", date = Sys.Date(), config = NULL){

  plumber_ga(client, date, config)

}
```